# which is performance better, indexedslicesquery or rangeslicesquery of hector?

Tags: cassandra, hector

When I using cassandra, I have faced a performance bottleneck of cassandra reading.

There is two ways of reading my data, which is huge of row keys. The first one is using indexs and query by indexed slices query api.  The second one is using rangeslicequery api, because of the row is sequence.

When I using indexes, it always throw timeoutexception. Then I wonder whether the rangeslicequery is performance better?

The cf with 200k rows and 3m columns. The query with retrieve 20k rows.

The key cache is 30000.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in this instance you are probably going to be better off using range_slice_query. It streams data off disk in chunks rather than doing random reads for each indexed entry (I think this is how get_indexed_slices works). The only way to be sure is to try both and compare them.

To stop the timeouts, you can either reduce the number of rows returned with each query (the "count" http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API/) or increase the timeout length you are using with hector.

Have you considered using hadoop to do what you are trying to do? 20k rows is quite a lot, it would probably be better suited for your task. There is an InputFormat provided with the cassandra source code that can be used. It uses range queries underneath, that check beforehand which node to query for each range of tokens. This is probably the fastest way to do your query. Here is the documentation on that http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport.